# Android webview causing click listener not to trigger

Tags: android, android-webview, listener

I have a ListView that has a list of articles.  Every X articles (10 currently), I have a WebView that shows an ad.  I can click on any list item EXCEPT the one just above the one where the WebView is displayed.  That one won't register my click.

**Code that shows or hides the WebView:**

```
if(position % 10 == 0) // || position == 0) && position > 0
{
    viewHolder.adView.loadUrl(tmpAdURL);
    viewHolder.adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
else
{
    viewHolder.adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    viewHolder.adView.invalidate();
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/articles_list"
    style="@style/ListView"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="16dp"
    android:divider="@color/extreme_light_gray"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
```

**Listener in MainActivty.java's onCreate():**

```
articleEntryListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Log.d("MINE", "ARTICLE CLICKED");
    }
}
```

**article_entry_list_item.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="60dp" >

    <!-- Title of the news entry -->

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/article_thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/articleThumbnail"
        android:cropToPadding="true"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0.5dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
        <!-- WAS: android:padding="0.5dp" -->



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/article_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/article_thumbnail"
        android:minHeight="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_title"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/articleTitle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/list_title_selector"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/article_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/articleSubtitle"
            android:textColor="@drawable/list_subtitle_selector"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/article_ad"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:background="@color/meddark_gray"
        android:layout_below="@+id/article_thumbnail"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are wasting resources using one row layout. Think of it: you create a WebView in all of the rows, but you immediately hide them (over) 90% of the time... Instead you should use a custom adapter with two row layouts by overriding these methods:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 11 == 0 ? 1 :  0;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

Next inside `getView()` or `newView()` check which type of layout you should load. Inflate the news item layout when `getItemViewType()` returns 0 and inflate a WebView (by itself) when it returns 1.

Aside from being faster and more organized, your WebView has it's own row now and should play nice.

Comment: Totally agree, just wasn't sure how (I'm still Android-noob).  Thanks - will try to implement this and check back asap.

Answer (score 0):

This may be similar to the issue I had with a `CheckBox` in a list item. Try using the `android:focusable="false"` option for the `WebView` in your list item XML.

In my case the `CheckBox` was taking focus from the list items and it prevented the event from firing for some reason.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/article_ad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@color/meddark_gray"
    android:layout_below="@+id/article_thumbnail"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:focusable="false" />
```

You're also able to do this in the code behind with

```
setFocusable(false);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to have no effect.